# Google earth plugin authentication and caching

Tags: tomcat, credentials, google-earth-plugin

Looking for confirmation of the following behavior from the GE plugin.

Using tomcat setup with BASIC authN, I get prompted for user/pass.  Upon navigating to a page that loads GE (version 7.0.3.x) and fetches KML that references icons `<Icon><href>...</href></Icon>` from the same server, I get prompted again for login credentials.  I suspect this is by design as Chris Cashwell comments,

> "...the Google Earth plugin, which acts as it's own user agent, and
>   won't pass along any session or cookie info from the browser's
>   session."

From this point forward, if I don't clear browser cache, I do not get prompted when the GE page is loaded.

Is there some documentation I missed that explains this or otherwise is this known to be true?

Secondly, I believe there may be a bug around credential caching where I see this behaviour: I clear all browser cache and login as User "jeff" (twice as above).  I restart the browser and login as User "fred".  Looking at server access logs, I see the `<Icon>` images are requested as User "jeff" instead of "fred".  If this sounds like a bug, I will file it if someone can give me a pointer to the appropriate trouble ticket system.

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [27/Jun/2013:12:07:21 -0500] "GET /examples/earth.html HTTP/1.1" 401 951
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - jeff [27/Jun/2013:12:07:24 -0500] "GET /examples/earth.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1628
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2013:12:07:32 -0500] "GET /examples/icons/icon_map_128x128_cat2.png HTTP/1.1" 401 951
127.0.0.1 - jeff [27/Jun/2013:12:07:36 -0500] "GET /examples/icons/icon_map_128x128_cat2.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [27/Jun/2013:12:08:18 -0500] "GET /examples/earth.html HTTP/1.1" 401 951
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - fred [27/Jun/2013:12:08:24 -0500] "GET /examples/earth.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1628
127.0.0.1 - jeff [27/Jun/2013:12:08:24 -0500] "GET /examples/icons/icon_map_128x128_cat4.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```